# INSERT variable values into a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have several variables in an SSIS package that I would like inserting into a table.

example:-

```
@financialMonth, @Status, @Comments
```

The Variables have been populated along the way with values based on lookups, filename, dates, etc, and I want to store them in a results table.

Is using the execute SQL task the way to do this ?

Do I need to call a sproc and pass those variales as parameters ?

I've tried putting the following T-SQL into the SQLStatement property

```
INSERT INTO FilesProcessed 
   (ProcessedOn, ProviderCode, FinancialMonth, 
   FileName, Status, Comments) 
SELECT     GETDATE(), 'ABC' , 201006, 
   'ABC_201005_Testology.csv', 
   'Imported','Success'
```

I tried hardcoding the values above to get it to work

These are the columns on the table I'm inserting into

```
Column_name     Type         Computed  Length
fileID          int          no          4
ProcessedOn     datetime     no          8
ProviderCode    nchar        no          6
FinancialMonth  int          no          4
FileName        nvarchar     no        510
Status          nvarchar     no         40
Comments        nvarchar     no        510
```

This is the Expression code that feeds the SQLStatementSource property

```
"INSERT INTO FilesProcessed (ProcessedOn, ProviderCode, FinancialMonth, 
  FileName, Status, Comments) SELECT     GETDATE() AS ProcessedOn, '"
  + @[User::providerCode] + "' , " 
  + (DT_STR,6,1252)@[User::financialMonth] + ", '" 
  + @[User::fileName] + "', 'Imported' AS Status,'Successfully' AS Comments "
```

Unfortunately I'm missing something, and can't quite get it to work.

> The Error message I'm getting is ...
>   Error: 0xC002F210 at Log entry in
>   FilesProcessed, Execute SQL Task:
>   Executing the query "INSERT INTO
>   FilesProcessed (ProcessedOn,
>   ProviderCode, FinancialMonth,
>   FileName, Status, Comments) SELECT
>   GETDATE(), 'ABC' , 201006,
>   'DAG_201005_Testology.csv',
>   'Imported','Successfully'" failed with
>   the following error: "An error
>   occurred while extracting the result
>   into a variable of type (DBTYPE_I2)".
>   Possible failure reasons: Problems
>   with the query, "ResultSet" property
>   not set correctly, parameters not set
>   correctly, or connection not
>   established correctly.

Please

a). Advise whether the Execute SQL Task is the way to do what I want to do.

b). Give me any pointers or pitfalls to look out for and check.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like it should work to me from what I remember about SSIS. (though obviously the code you posted isn't using the variables at all) What error are you getting?

Comment: try removing "as status" and "as comments"

Comment: I've pasted the Expression code that I used to create the T-SQL. I was trying to hard code the T-SQL to see if the simpler code worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, here is what I did.

I created an Execute SQL task and configured, thus :-

```
General Tab
  ConnectionType = OLE DB
  SQLSourceType = Direct Input
  SQLStatement = (left blank)
  BypassPrepare = True
  ResultSet = None

Parameter Mapping
  (none - leave blank)

Result Set
  (none - leave blank)

Expressions
  SQLStatementSource = "INSERT INTO FilesProcessed (ProcessedOn, ProviderCode, FinancialMonth, FileName, Status, Comments) SELECT GETDATE(), '" + @[User::providerCode] + "' , " + (DT_STR,6,1252)@[User::financialMonth] + ", '" + @[User::fileName] + "', 'Import - Success', '" + @[User::fileComments] + "'"
```

Then as long as I set up the variables and populate them in the variables window (the Expression editor will not let you save an expression that references a variable that does not exist. Keep notepad handy to store the contents while you go back and edit the variables window, and add new variables in ;)

Build the expression slowly, using the Parse expression button regularly to check.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that the data types of the VALUES match the destination column data types.

see: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/e8f82288-b980-40a7-83a6-914e217f247d/

Answer (score 0):

A couple of speculative suggestions

1. The Error message says An error occurred while extracting **the result** into a variable of type (DBTYPE_I2). But this is a straight insert statement. There shouldn't be a result except for rows affected. Do you have any parameter mappings erroneously set to `Output`?
2. What if you try and run the SQL Query from the error message directly in management studio? Does that give you an error?

Answer (score 0):

In the above table definition FinancialMonth as int datatype as

**FinancialMonth  int          no          4**

while inseting casting as :

```
(DT_STR,6,1252)@[User::financialMonth]
```

I think it's purely a datatype mismatch with the target table definition.