# Import/Insert Excel Range and SSIS variables into SQL table?

Tags: sql, excel, variables, ssis

I have an SSIS package that is to ingest a number of Excel files with similar structures but irregular names and import them into a SQL table. Along with the data from the excel files, I have a number of variables that are set and different with each file (User::ExcelFileName, User::VarMonth, User::VarProgram, User::VarYear, etc). All of the table data from the Excel files are going to the same destination table, but for each row of data alongside the Excel dataset I want to insert a column for each variable to pass through as well into SQL. An example of my dataset is below:

**Excel**

| ID | Name | Foo | Bar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Bob | 88yu | 117 |
| 112 | Jim | JKL | A TU |
| 113 | George | FTD | 19900 |

**SSIS Variables (set during execution)**

User::ExcelFileName = c:\temp\excelfile1.xlsx

User::VarMonth = Jan

User::VarProgram =  Daily

User::VarYear = 2023

**Desired SQL Destination:**

| ExcelFileName | VarMonth | VarProgram | VarYear | ID | Name | Foo | Bar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c:\temp\excelfile1.xlsx | Jan | Daily | 2023 | 111 | Bob | 88yu | 117 |
| c:\temp\excelfile1.xlsx | Jan | Daily | 2023 | 112 | Jim | JKL | A TU |
| c:\temp\excelfile1.xlsx | Jan | Daily | 2023 | 113 | George | FTD | 19900 |

I've tried a few configurations and I've referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308048/insert-variable-values-into-a-table) post for piping in variable data into SQL, but I haven't gotten a working model yet.

Worth noting, Excel COnnection is dynamic and set to run within a Foreach Loop container to iterate through my Excel sources. Any advice or guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a Derived Column task.
in the task, just add the new columns you want, and map the variables to the column.

[image]

Comment: This wound up producing the expected results, many thanks!